# elasticsearch multi_match vs should

Tags: elasticsearch

Can someone tell me the difference between

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            { "match": {"title": keyword} },
            { "match": {"description": keyword} }
        ]
    }
```

and

```
"query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": keyword,
            "fields": [ "title", "description" ]
        }
    }
```

Is there any performance turning if choose one of two above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on the [type parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types) of your `multi_match`. In your example, since you didn't specify a type, [best_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-best-fields) is used. That makes use of a [Dis Max Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) and basically

> uses the _score from the best field

On the other hand, your example with `should`

> combines the _score from each field.

and it is equivalent to `multi_match` with type [most_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#type-most-fields)

Comment: Thank you @Mario, for more details: [elasticsearch what is the difference between best_field and most_field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393793/elasticsearch-what-is-the-difference-between-best-field-and-most-field).