# elasticsearch what is the difference between best_field and most_field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I already ready this article
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

but couldn't figure it out myself.

lets have these two queries:

**first**

```
GET blablabla/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "games usa",
      "fields": ["title1", "title2"],
      "type": "best_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

**second**

```
get blablabla/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "games usa",
      "fields": ["title1", "title2"],
      "type": "most_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

I think the first query means:

> get documetns that contain (games) or (usa) or (games and usa)  words in either the title1 or the title2 fields.

However, I don't know what does the second one mean.

may i ask for help please?

(im on elasticsearch 2.2)

Answer (score 33):

Whenever search operation is performed in `Elastic Search`, relevance of each matched document is calculated.According to th documentation-

> The relevance score of each document is represented by a positive floating-point number called the `_score`. The higher the _score, the more relevant the document.

As per your examples mentioned above

```
GET blablabla/_search
{
"query": {
"multi_match": {
  "query": "games usa",
  "fields": ["title1", "title2"],
  "type": "best_fields"
   }
  }
}
```

This query will find the documents which contain `games` **AND/OR** `usa` in `title1` or `title2` but `_score` will be calculated from **single** best matching field. For example-

- if `title1` contains `games` and `title2` contains `games usa` in the same document, then `_score` will be the one from `title2`.
- `best_fields` is most useful when you are searching for multiple words best found in the same field.

In `most_fields`:

```
GET blablabla/_search
{ 
"query" : {
"multi_match": {
  "query": "games usa",
  "fields": ["title1", "title2"],
  "type": "most_fields"
   }
  }
}
```

This query will find the documents which contain `games` **AND/OR** `usa` in `title1` or `title2` but `_score` will be calculated from the combination of all the fields. For example-

- if `title1` contains `games` and `title2` contains `games usa` in the same document, then `_score` will be combination of scores from `title1` and `title2`

Hope this helps

Comment: very nice explanation

Comment: Very clear explanation @Richa

Answer (score 3):

A little remark for most_fields - it uses score from both fields. and divide it on fields count

In your example:
( Score from title1 + score from title2 ) / 2